# I have accidentally removed apt-get and aptitude (Debian 6)

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get, aptitude

After I have removed libusb-0.1-4 packet, I tried to install a new one when I realized that I have also removed apt-get.

`tbarry@darkstar:~$ sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0
sudo: apt-get: command not found
tbarry@darkstar:~$ sudo aptitude install libusb-1.0-0
sudo: aptitude: command not found`

could someone know how to reinstall apt without apt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the `apt...version.deb` from https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=apt and then install it via `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/apt..version.deb`. As long a dpkg is not removed everything is recoverable. Then install `aptitude` via `apt-get`.

Answer (score 2):

You could download the `apt` (or `aptitude`) package in `.deb` form with `wget` (or any other HTTP or FTP client), then use `dpkg -i` to install that `apt*.deb` package.

If `dpkg` complains about a missing dependency, install that dependency likewise.